# Angular form validation: compare two fields in different form groups

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm sorry if it's a duplicate of someone question. I didn't find a solution for my problem.

Can anybody explain or give an example how to compare two fields in one form but in different form groups?

Here is code snippet to see how my form and validator are look like:

```
private createForm() {

    const testGroups = {
        groupOne: this.fb.group({
            fieldOne: this.fb.control(null)
        }),
        groupsTwo: this.fb.group({
            fieldTwo: this.fb.control(null, [this.matchValidator])
        })
    };

    this.testForm = this.fb.group(testGroups);
}

 matchValidator(from: FormControl): ValidatorFn {
    return (to: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
        return from.value && to.value && from.value === to.value
            ? { fieldMatch: true }
            : null;
    };
}
```

Comment: I guess you could use root property of the control

Comment: @Florian thanks for reply. Can you provide an example where should I bind validator? Whiat should I pass? And what I should to return (I think it's defenetly not `AbstractControl`)?

Comment: @hofshteyn, give my answer a try.

Answer (score 2):

`matchValidator` will be called by Angular and not by you. So it won't have the access to the Component's `this`.

So you will have to bind to it.

You can use the `get` method on a `FormGroup` to get the `group1`'s `field`'s value: `(<FormGroup>this.mainForm.get('group1')).get('field').value`

Give this a try:

Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  mainForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
      group1: this.fb.group({
        field: []
      }),
      group2: this.fb.group({
        field: [null, [this.matchValidator.bind(this)]]
      })
    });

  }

  matchValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
    const fromValue = control.value;
    if(this.mainForm) {
      const toValue = (<FormGroup>this.mainForm.get('group1')).get('field').value;
      if (fromValue && toValue && fromValue === toValue) {
        console.log('Control: ', control);
        return { 'fieldMatch' : true };
      }
      console.log('Control: ', control);
      return null;
    }
  }

  get group2Field() {
    return (<FormGroup>this.mainForm.get('group2')).get('field');
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="mainForm">
  <div formGroupName="group1">
    <label for="">Group 1 Field</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="field">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div formGroupName="group2">
    <label for="">Group 2 Field</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="field">
    <p *ngIf="group2Field?.errors?.fieldMatch">These fields match</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-compare-fields-in-different-groups?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: It's a good answer. But what if we have a dynamically creating groups? I mean what if we don't know how many groups will be? For example if I'll create a form via iterating of some array? 

I need a universal validator to validate all fields inside

Comment: @hofshteyn, I think you're pivoting from the original question here. Please consider asking a different question with all the relevant details. Or you should have specified all the relevant details in the OP in the first place. I'm suggesting this as this way it won't create any additional noise on this thread. Just keeps the site clean and accurate. :)