# select drop down change passing mode in angular 9

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular9, angular-bootstrap

All am passing value in drop down change method based on the passing value only i have do some validations to enable submit button.And also i need to compare two drop down value in that case i dont know how to handle it in angular 9.And the passed value is with position kindly find the screen shot

```
 <label for="aCount" class="required">testcount</label>
                <select id="testCounts" class="form-control" formControlName="testcount" #testcount
                    (change)='ontestCountSelected(testcount.value)'>

                    <option *ngFor="let count of testcountsVal" [ngValue]="count.count">
                        {{ count.count }}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <div class="text-danger"
                    *ngIf="submitted && listForm.controls.testcount.hasError('required')">
                    Select count is required
                </div>
            </div>
 public testcountsVal: any[] = [
    { count: '0' },
    { count: '1' },
    { count: '2' },
    { count: '3' },
    { count: '4' }
  ];
        ontestCountSelected(value: string) {
        console.log(value);
         }
```

So here am having two questions:
1) one is how do we compare two different drop down model in angular 9.
2) why am getting value with position in console when am passing value onchange method in drop down

Kindly find the attachment.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set `formControlName` same as variable `#testcount`.

You need change `#testcount` to `#testcount1` and use as `(change)='ontestCountSelected(testcount1.value)'`

```
<label for="aCount" class="required">testcount</label>
<select id="testCounts" class="form-control" formControlName="testcount" #testcount1
      (change)='ontestCountSelected(testcount1.value)'>

      <option *ngFor="let count of testcountsVal" [ngValue]="count.count">
                        {{ count.count }}
      </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Hien Nguyen how do we compare two select boxes model for validation?

Comment: you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426241/4964569

Comment: i did the changes what you given as a solution but still am having same problem in console